# Tolman-Bondi-Lemaitre space times

Tags: differential-geometry

One can see [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=rIyIlQwVCgkC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=TBL+spacetimes&source=bl&ots=uu2rVqvCtn&sig=JqwYqPgtBEXK_SIwEOjZFxhNKzY&hl=en&ei=50FxTPz-Mo_mvQPI8NxB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=TBL%20spacetimes&f=false) for TBL space-times.

I would like to know how the explicit expression for the function called $G$ in equations $3.108,3.108,3.110$ in the above reference is obtained.

Also it would be nice to see some further references about TBL space-times.

Comment: [ad] This site is about Mathematics. If you are interested in Physics, you may want to check out the [Physics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=8DOyF6Jxxs0N5QfMOt5KEg2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually just comes from integration. Equation 3.106 from that book is

$$ \dot R^2 = \left( - \frac{\partial R}{\partial t} \right)^2 = \frac FR + f $$

rearranging the terms gives (note that $\dot R < 0$)

$$ dt = - \frac{dR}{\sqrt{\frac FR + f}} $$

Now perform the substitution $z = fR/F$, giving

$$ dt = -\frac F{f^{3/2}} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+\frac1z}}. $$

Integrating gives

$$ t - t_0 = \frac F{f^{3/2}} \left( \sinh^{-1}\sqrt z - \sqrt{z(z+1)}\right) $$

the rest is just algebra.

I am no expert on general relativity, but the common term of that TBL spacetime seems start with "[Lemaitre-Tolman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemaitre%E2%80%93Tolman_metric)". There is a review article [on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2044)<sup>[1]</sup> which might help.

<sup>[1]: Kari Enqvist (2008). *Lemaitre–Tolman–Bondi model and accelerating expansion*. General Relativity and Gravitation **40**, 2–3, pp 451–466. DOI: 10.1007/s10714-007-0553-9.</sup>